# How can I give time to a progressbar in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, progress-bar

I want to use a progressbar in Android Studio and my app is in Kotlin.

How may I give time to a progressbar to be complete?

[image]

Comment: Please add more details, its unclear of what you want.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar#determinate-progress

Comment: What do you mean by *"give time to a progressbar"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean it is possible that set the progressbar to be complete in 3 seconds?@Peter Mortensen

Comment: You mean show it for 3 seconds (and then remove it)? That is, show it ***immediately*** and remove it after 3 seconds have passed?

Comment: Yes, if you have another and better answer than the correct answer, please give me that answer @Peter Mortensen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this with basically;

```
Handler().postDelayed({
          menuProgressBar!!.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
     },5000/* 5 second */)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Murat Çakır